# Perform specific SQL query on Laravel

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent, union, query-builder

I have an application that manages **shops**, **users** and **roles**.

Each user could be an **owner**, **supervisor**, **employee** or **admin**.

The way to know if a user has **admin**, **supervisor** or **employee** permissions is through the **role_user** table that connects the users, the shops and the roles (the **admin** role sets **NULL** value in **shop_id** field on the **role_shop** table). The owner, instead, is obtained by the **user_id** field on the **shops** table.

I would like to perform a function on my user model that gets all the roles that a user has.

The following query works but I don't know how to perform it on Eloquent's Query Builder

```
SELECT priority, role, shop
FROM (
    (
        SELECT 1.5 AS priority, "owner" AS role, shops.id AS shop
        FROM shops
        WHERE shops.user_id = 1
    )

    UNION

    (
        SELECT roles.id AS priority, roles.name AS role, role_shop.shop_id AS shop
        FROM role_shop
        JOIN roles ON (roles.id = role_shop.role_id)        
        WHERE role_shop.user_id = 1
    )

) AS result
ORDER BY priority
```

Thanks for your help folks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have two selects here, I will suggest to make two queries first then join the two queries to get the union result.

```
$query1 = Shop::select(
    DB::RAW('"1.5" AS "priority"'),
    DB::RAW('"owner" AS "role"'),
    DB::RAW('id AS "shop"')
  )
  ->where('user_id', 1)
  ->orderBy('priority');

$query2 = RoleShop::join('roles AS roles', 'role_shop.role_id', '=', 'roles.id')
  ->select(
      DB::RAW('roles.id AS "priority"'),
      DB::RAW('roles.name AS "role"'),
      DB::RAW('role_shop.shop_id AS "shop"'),
  )
  ->where('role_shop.user_id', 1)
  ->orderBy('priority');

$result = $query1->union($query2)->get();
```

It may not be 100% correct but feel free to tweak it to get what you want.

[Reference](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries#unions)

Comment: You are awesome, my friend. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Use `join` method and group the result by `user_id`

```
$roles = DB::table('roles')
->where('user_id', '=', 1)
->join('shops', 'shops.user_id', '=', 'roles.user_id')
//Add other tabalse as join then
->select('roles.*')
->groupby('roles.user_id')
->get();
```

> Ps: Sorry my code is not complete, I'm with mobile, you can find
>   samples in laravel docs

Comment: Thanks for the reply! But this solution doesn't work due to the owner is not a role since it is a field on the shops table